# ipad & iphone have been compromised

Tags: iphone

Please help me. Someone has supposedly used a clean up app on my iPhone & iPad.
Spoke with Google & they said I need to talk with Apple. Of course with the Holiday that is impossible. I found it going into my contacts. My name was in my contact list. Clicked on it & found my email accounts & Twitter. He has also got 
in my calender & has revised it. There was a note that said use my photo & name for a Unified card. Looked online but not specific on exactly  what a Unified is & how the hell did he do it.any advice ASAP...would be a blessing. Just bought a new laptop & has u can see, not to savey with it yet.

Sincerley,
Karen

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're asking. What is a "Clean up app"? How do contacts have anything to do about this? Who is this other person? What does Google have to do with this?

Comment: That is what a Google tech told me. I have no idea. He has been linking all my accounts, apps, etc.

Comment: How did a Google tech get involved in this?  Did you contact Google Support because your Google account was compromised?  Have you contacted [Apple Support here](https://support.apple.com/contact)?

Answer (score 2):

> Someone has supposedly used a clean up app on my iPhone & iPad.

That would be you. Where did you install the app from? Is your phone jailbroken with strange apps installed from random websites?

> My name was in my contact list. Clicked on it & found my email accounts & Twitter.

That's normal. you are supposed to have a record in Contacts that identifies you.

It is highly unlikely that your phone has been compromised. You may remember recently that the FBI had some difficulty getting into one. Malware is basically non-existant on the iPhone platform.

However, it is quite likely that your iCloud account has been compromised if you used poor passwords ("Karen1234", "P@ssw0rd" and so on.)

> He has been linking all my accounts, apps, etc.

Who is "He"? A google technician won't do that. Someone pretending to be a google technician might try in order to get access to your account.

Big question: have you told your account password to *anyone* for any reason? If yes, change it now. And don't do that again.